# SQL Join Duplicate Results

Tags: mysql, sql, join, concatenation

I've been learning SQL to a slightly more advanced degree than usual, and I am a little bit stuck on this one.

The query is to get all of the airports that an airline flies to (destinations) from a user inputted origin.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.airline_name, GROUP_CONCAT(ap.city) AS groupedDestinations
            FROM routes AS r
            LEFT JOIN airlines AS a
                ON r.airline = a.airline_iata
            LEFT JOIN airports AS ap
                ON r.destination = ap.airport_iata
            WHERE r.origin = ? AND a.active="Y" AND r.codeshare != "Y"
            GROUP BY a.airline_name ASC
```

The result should be:

```
Airline Name | city1, city2
```

Instead it is:

```
Airline Name | city1, city2, city1, city2
```

It's taken me a few hours to get to this point so I would appreciate any advice, abuse or answers :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `group by`you do *not* need `distinct` in the `select` clause.

The issue that you have is that airlines may have more than one route to a given city.  This results in duplicates for the cities.  By default, `group_concat()` does not remove these duplicates.  To fix this, you want `distinct` in the `group_concat`:

```
SELECT a.airline_name, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct ap.city) AS groupedDestinations
            FROM routes AS r
            LEFT JOIN airlines AS a
                ON r.airline = a.airline_iata
            LEFT JOIN airports AS ap
                ON r.destination = ap.airport_iata
            WHERE r.origin = ? AND a.active="Y" AND r.codeshare != "Y"
            GROUP BY a.airline_name ASC;
```

Comment: -_- 

I'm going to bed....

I thought distinct had something to do with it and I've spent the last hour or two flicking through this site which is an amazing resource.

Thank you so very, very much, that was unbelievably helpful. Hopefully it will help someone else in the same situation.